# SVG animateTransform rotation of a linearGradient is not centered. How to center it?

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to make a rotating linear gradient, but if I use the `animateTransform` to rotate it the gradient it's not centered:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 13 13" width="200px" height="200px" fill="none">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>
  <linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
    <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to obtain this result with the animateTransform?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 13 13" width="200px" height="200px" fill="none">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>
  <linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
    <animate attributeName="x1" dur="2s" values="0%;0%;50%;100%;100%;100%;50%;0%;0%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="y1" dur="2s" values="50%;0%;0%;0%;50%;100%;100%;100%;50%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="x2" dur="2s" values="100%;100%;50%;0%;0%;0%;50%;100%;100%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="y2" dur="2s" values="50%;100%;100%;100%;50%;0%;0%;0%;50%" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the value for the rotation like this:

```
gradientTransform="rotate(30 0.5 0.5)"
```

meaning that the gradient is rotated 30 degs around the center.

For the animation I'm using the attribute `values` instead of from and to. Tne `values` attribute is a list of values separated by `;`. This way you can use the value for the rotation with the rotation center

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 13 13" width="200px" height="200px" fill="none">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>
  <linearGradient id="grad"  gradientTransform="rotate(0 0.5 0.5)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
    <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform" type="rotate" values="0 0.5 0.5; 360 0.5 0.5" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

And yes, in order to achieve the same result you can use the `from` and `to` attributes as well

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 13 13" width="200px" height="200px" fill="none">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>
  <linearGradient id="grad"  gradientTransform="rotate(0 0.5 0.5)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
    <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform" type="rotate" from="0 0.5 0.5" to="360 0.5 0.5" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't find anywhere all the gradientTransform properties in the detail